# Exiting a block enclosed in curly braces in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

Say if I have the following code in Sublime:

```
if (condition) {
    // code
}
```

When my cursor is at the end of `// code`, I would like to set a key bind (e.g. Tab) that will exit the if-statement block and move it to the end of `}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) plugin can provide this functionality natively... sort of. In its example shortcuts file, `Example.sublime-keymap`, there is a "Go to Right Bracket" example key binding:

```
// Go to right bracket
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+down"],
    "command": "bh_key",
    "args":
    {
        "lines" : true,
        "plugin":
        {
            "type": ["__all__"],
            "command": "bh_modules.bracketselect",
            "args": {"select": "right"}
        }
    }
},
```

The only problem is that the called `bracketselect` command moves the cursor to the **left side** of the right bracket, requiring another keypress to fully escape from the block. I don't think that's what you want.

Worry not! Thankfully, BracketHighlighter provides a very intuitive plugin API, and I found that I could modify the `bracketselect` plugin to create a command that would escape from a bracket-enclosed block—basically the same as `bracketselect`, but it moves the cursor to the **right side** of the closing bracket rather than the left, and doesn't need any extra arguments.

You'll first need to install [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) if you haven't yet.

Next, save [blockescape.py](https://gist.github.com/ProtractorNinja/5608300) (see below if the link ever dies) to

```
Preferences -> Browse Packages... -> BracketHighlighter/bh_modules/blockescape.py
```

Then, add this entry to the top of your user key bindings (`Preferences -> Key Bindings — User`):

```
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "bh_key",
    "args":
    {
        "lines" : true,
        "plugin":
        {
            "type": ["__all__"],
            "command": "bh_modules.blockescape"
        }
    }
},
```

I wouldn't recommend using `tab` as your trigger key, because `tab` has an important role already with expansions. Of course, you could define a special [context](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) in which to use `tab`, but that is up to you.

**In case Github is ever down, here's the plugin code:**

```python
import bh_plugin
import sublime

DEFAULT_TAGS = ["cfml", "html", "angle"]


class BlockEscape(bh_plugin.BracketPluginCommand):
    def run(self, edit, name, tags=DEFAULT_TAGS):
        current_left, current_right = self.selection[0].begin(), self.selection[0].end()
        left, right = self.left, self.right
        first, last = left.end, right.begin
        if left.end != right.end:
            if name in tags and left.size() > 1:
                first, last = right.begin + 1, right.begin + 1
                if first == current_left and last == current_right:
                    first, last = right.end, right.end
            else:
                first, last = right.begin, right.begin
                if first == current_left and last == current_right:
                    first, last = right.end, right.end
        else:
            # There is no second bracket, so just select the first
            if name in tags and left.size() > 1:
                first, last = left.begin + 1, left.begin + 1
            else:
                first, last = right.end, right.end
                if first == current_left and last == current_right:
                    first, last = right.end, right.end

        self.selection = [sublime.Region(first+1, last+1)]


def plugin():
    return BlockEscape
```

Since I more or less hacked the plugin together, it might not work properly. In that case, feel free to edit it yourself or leave a comment on the [Gist page](https://gist.github.com/ProtractorNinja/5608300).

Comment: Thank you so much, I have the key bind set to shift+enter, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `$0` in a snippet to tab to that location:

```
<snippet>
    <description>If Condition</description>
    <content><![CDATA[if (${1:/* condition */}){
      ${2:/* code */}
    }${0}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>if</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.c</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: This answer is related to writing snippets, not the general case of writing code as the question implies. Are you sure it's an appropriate response?

Comment: The answer addresses the OP's question.  Plugins and snippets are how these tasks are best accomplished in ST2.

Comment: The snippet you gave me will only work for specific cases. What I'm asking is to be able to "tab out" of a statement - it can be if, while, for, etc. Another example is I have a key binding that allows me to tab out of brackets and quotes when I press Tab before the closing bracket/quote. But this only works in-line.

Comment: That is not what you asked in your OP.